# Selecting data from the result of an ORDER BY query

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have this sql query:

```
SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY votes LIMIT 3
```

That is loaded on one page. How do I get the the next 3 by providing the ID of the last one retrieved(`1`). Example of a table:

```
ID votes
--------
 4   29
45   26
 1   23
 7   13
23    5
 9    2
```

Comment: Ah, if only the documentation spoke to this situa- oh wait. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: Aha, thank u. I was thinking of selecting the nest 3 by providing an ID when I could instead provide an offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use offset `SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT offset,limit`.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY votes LIMIT 3,3
```

Comment: Thank you to all of you. Since you all have the same answers, I just gave u gays one vote up for the effort and idea you spent and gave. Good day!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY votes LIMIT 3, 3
```

You can select range using limit. Ex Limit x,y where x=start, y=length

**EDIT:**

Since you saying that you want to get this by passing the id. You can obtain relevant data set using following kind of query.

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE votes <= (SELECT votes FROM questions WHERE id = 1) AND id != 1 ORDER BY  votes DESC LIMIT 3
```

However there is an issue if you have multiple records with same votes. So I would like to suggest you keep the record count you have displaced so far.

```
$displayed = 0;
$rowsPerPage = 3;
```

So you can simply get data by passing these parameters without an issue.

```
$start = 1;
if($displayed >0)
$start = $displayed + $rowsPerPage;
```

$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY votes LIMIT $start, $rowsPerPage ";

In next page load or pagination increase `$displayed`.

```
$displayed +=  $rowsPerPage;
```

You have to keep  $displayed as a Session if you have page loads, Otherwise it could be a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `LIMIT <offset>, <count>` tag instead of the id of the last on retrieved, since you are ordering by votes, not by id.

```
SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY votes LIMIT 3, 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below

Set 1 : `SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY votes LIMIT 3`

Set 2 : `SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY votes LIMIT 4, 3`

Set 3 : `SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY votes LIMIT 7, 3`

and so on...

You need to keep on changing the `offset` value...

### Good Luck!!!